# Adding okio jar file to build path causes "Import (xxx) cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I've downloaded Selenium WebDriver 3.141.59 from the Selenium download page and added it to the build path of my Project, but for some reason okio-1.14.0.jar causes my code to give me the import cannot be resolved error.

```
package IS338SeleniumPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class IS338SeleniumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }
}
```

Naturally, not having the okio jar makes it impossible to run, so I'm wondering what it is about that file and/or my code/pathing that's causing the issue.

[Here's an image of my project files in the Eclipse package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dRtd.png) in case it helps.